# Retrieving data from an xmlblob header

Tags: sql-server, syntax

I am using SQL Server 2017, I have been able to pull out script data using SQL like this

```
rhXMLBlob.value('(/RuntimeScript/RuntimePage/RuntimeVariable[@name=''CALL_CLI''])[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS [CLI]
```

but I need to get at the header data basically the ABORT reason ie everything after outcome= (here ‘ABORT - looking for property, directed to website’) I can’t quite get the syntax to work.

```
<RuntimeScript previewmode="no" outcome="ABORT - Looking for property, directed to website" ocu="20" starttime="12/12/2018 11:44:03" endtime="12/12/2018 11:45:47" scriptid="73440180-0149-4BAE-A6BC-08243778C1B1" versionid="48" accountno="106868" operatorid="92" operatorinitials="MBI" operatorname="Mikaela Bigland" callref="3XXXPPCQ" channel="" ddi="01156979471" jobcode="0" billingaccount="" cli="07444019309" activationid="f54090a4-82e2-4c84-b273-e1d0167b725f" work_object_id="" work_lock_id="" work_request_id="" message_guid="1646c00e-c06c-47ed-abc3-f1d615e105e0" instanceid="7f7c26d5-829e-47be-8e3d-02b463a7e623" sequence="1" searchkey="">
  <RuntimePage pageid="1">
    <RuntimeVariable name="iWorkProcessing" />
    <RuntimeVariable name="iResultsProcessing" />
    <RuntimeVariable name="QUERY_XML">&lt;NewDataSet&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;iDataRowId&gt;2a016220-99a1-44bb-8933-17c143b92eb2&lt;/iDataRowId&gt;
    &lt;iDataRowId2&gt;6ac4f348-359d-44e1-9f2f-aadeedbbe4b3&lt;/iDataRowId2&gt;

  &lt;/Table&gt;
&lt;/NewDataSet&gt;</RuntimeVariable>
    <RuntimeVariable name="SCRIPT_LAUNCH_REASON">Inbound call</RuntimeVariable>
    <RuntimeVariable name="INBOUND_DDI">01156979471</RuntimeVariable>
    <RuntimeVariable name="CALL_CLI">07444019309</RuntimeVariable>
    <RuntimeVariable name="CALL_DATE">12 December 2018</RuntimeVariable>
    <RuntimeVariable name="CALL_TIME">11:44:03</RuntimeVariable>
    <RuntimeVariable name="DELIVERY_FLAG" />
    <RuntimeVariable name="CB_CONTENT">www.openrent.co.uk</RuntimeVariable>
    <RuntimeVariable name="NORMAL_CALL_TYPE_LB">Register interest / non viewing enquiry</RuntimeVariable>
    <RuntimeVariable name="LANDLORD_OR_TENANT_LB">Tenant</RuntimeVariable>
    <RuntimeVariable name="LANDLORD_ENQUIRY_DETAILS" />
    <RuntimeVariable name="LANDLORD_TEL" recipient="no" phonenumber_type="phone">
      <RuntimeVariable name="Number">07444019309</RuntimeVariable>
    </RuntimeVariable>
    <RuntimeVariable name="LANDLINE_INT_LANDLINE_LB" />
    <RuntimeVariable name="LANDLORD_EMAIL_ADDRESS" recipient="no" />
    <RuntimeVariable name="NO_VIEWING_TEL" recipient="no" phonenumber_type="phone">
      <RuntimeVariable name="Number">07444019309</RuntimeVariable>
    </RuntimeVariable>
    <RuntimeVariable name="NO_VIEWING_ENQUIRY_DETAILS" />
    <RuntimeVariable name="INT_LANDLINE_LB" />
    <RuntimeVariable name="NO_VIEWING_EMAIL_ADDRESS" recipient="no" />
    <RuntimeVariable name="PROPERTY_REF_LB" />
    <RuntimeVariable name="REFERENCE_NUMBER" />
    <RuntimeVariable name="PROPERTY_LOAD_OUTCOME" />
    <RuntimeVariable name="PROPERTY_SEARCH_FAIL_LB" />
    <RuntimeVariable name="PROPERTY_SEARCH_FAIL_NEXT_LB" />
    <RuntimeVariable name="REF_YES_TEL" recipient="no" phonenumber_type="phone">
      <RuntimeVariable name="Number">07444019309</RuntimeVariable>
    </RuntimeVariable>
    <RuntimeVariable name="MOBILE_YN" />
    <RuntimeVariable name="REF_YES_EMAIL_ADDRESS" recipient="no" />
    <RuntimeVariable name="REF_NO_TEL" recipient="no" phonenumber_type="phone">
      <RuntimeVariable name="Number">07444019309</RuntimeVariable>
    </RuntimeVariable>
    <RuntimeVariable name="PR_N_MOBILE_YN" />
    <RuntimeVariable name="REF_NO_EMAIL_ADDRESS" recipient="no" />
    <RuntimeVariable name="CLOSE_2_LB" />
  </RuntimePage>
</RuntimeScript>
```

I tried

```
rhXMLBlob.value('(/RuntimeScript[@outcome])[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS [outcome reason]
```

but that returned:

& l t;Table & g t;

and everything beneath it. I fell like I'm close but don't know the correct syntax. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please don't post your data as an image, especially a snippet of it; the image is effectively useless to anyone trying to help you as we can't even transcribe it. Post your data as **formatted** `text`.

Comment: I tried that but the formatting in the xml kept getting translated here

Comment: Also, when you post your formatted data, can you please provide the expected results as well.

Comment: I need ‘ABORT - looking for property, directed to website’ as I said above. Apologies if that wasn't clear enough. Or do you mean something different?

Comment: That XML isn't valid. If you try `SELECT CONVERT(xml, {The above XML});` you get the error: `XML parsing: line 14, character 62, unexpected end of input`. If you're using a `(n)varchar` to store invalid XML, then SQL Server is not the right tool to do this. SQL Server is far from good at string manipulation; you're be far better using a programmatic language, perhaps VB.net or C#.

Comment: I only added a snippet because there was a username and password field, I've added the full xml (but cut the username and password fields) sorry for making things difficult thanks for walking me through.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my answer now that I've been able to test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression you need is:

```
YourXmlColumn.value('(/RuntimeScript/@outcome)[1]','nvarchar(4000)')
```

You can test this below:

```
SELECT YourXmlColumn.value('(/RuntimeScript/@outcome)[1]','nvarchar(4000)'), V.YourXMLColumn
FROM (VALUES(CONVERT(xml,'    <RuntimeScript previewmode="no" outcome="ABORT - Looking for property, directed to website" ocu="20" starttime="12/12/2018 11:44:03" endtime="12/12/2018 11:45:47" scriptid="73440180-0149-4BAE-A6BC-08243778C1B1" versionid="48" accountno="106868" operatorid="92" operatorinitials="MBI" operatorname="Mikaela Bigland" callref="3XXXPPCQ" channel="" ddi="01156979471" jobcode="0" billingaccount="" cli="07444019309" activationid="f54090a4-82e2-4c84-b273-e1d0167b725f" work_object_id="" work_lock_id="" work_request_id="" message_guid="1646c00e-c06c-47ed-abc3-f1d615e105e0" instanceid="7f7c26d5-829e-47be-8e3d-02b463a7e623" sequence="1" searchkey="">
  <RuntimePage pageid="1">
    <RuntimeVariable name="iWorkProcessing" />
    <RuntimeVariable name="iResultsProcessing" />
    <RuntimeVariable name="QUERY_XML">&lt;NewDataSet&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;iDataRowId&gt;2a016220-99a1-44bb-8933-17c143b92eb2&lt;/iDataRowId&gt;
    &lt;iDataRowId2&gt;6ac4f348-359d-44e1-9f2f-aadeedbbe4b3&lt;/iDataRowId2&gt;

  &lt;/Table&gt;
&lt;/NewDataSet&gt;</RuntimeVariable>
    <RuntimeVariable name="SCRIPT_LAUNCH_REASON">Inbound call</RuntimeVariable>
    <RuntimeVariable name="INBOUND_DDI">01156979471</RuntimeVariable>
    <RuntimeVariable name="CALL_CLI">07444019309</RuntimeVariable>
    <RuntimeVariable name="CALL_DATE">12 December 2018</RuntimeVariable>
    <RuntimeVariable name="CALL_TIME">11:44:03</RuntimeVariable>
    <RuntimeVariable name="DELIVERY_FLAG" />
    <RuntimeVariable name="CB_CONTENT">www.openrent.co.uk</RuntimeVariable>
    <RuntimeVariable name="NORMAL_CALL_TYPE_LB">Register interest / non viewing enquiry</RuntimeVariable>
    <RuntimeVariable name="LANDLORD_OR_TENANT_LB">Tenant</RuntimeVariable>
    <RuntimeVariable name="LANDLORD_ENQUIRY_DETAILS" />
    <RuntimeVariable name="LANDLORD_TEL" recipient="no" phonenumber_type="phone">
      <RuntimeVariable name="Number">07444019309</RuntimeVariable>
    </RuntimeVariable>
    <RuntimeVariable name="LANDLINE_INT_LANDLINE_LB" />
    <RuntimeVariable name="LANDLORD_EMAIL_ADDRESS" recipient="no" />
    <RuntimeVariable name="NO_VIEWING_TEL" recipient="no" phonenumber_type="phone">
      <RuntimeVariable name="Number">07444019309</RuntimeVariable>
    </RuntimeVariable>
    <RuntimeVariable name="NO_VIEWING_ENQUIRY_DETAILS" />
    <RuntimeVariable name="INT_LANDLINE_LB" />
    <RuntimeVariable name="NO_VIEWING_EMAIL_ADDRESS" recipient="no" />
    <RuntimeVariable name="PROPERTY_REF_LB" />
    <RuntimeVariable name="REFERENCE_NUMBER" />
    <RuntimeVariable name="PROPERTY_LOAD_OUTCOME" />
    <RuntimeVariable name="PROPERTY_SEARCH_FAIL_LB" />
    <RuntimeVariable name="PROPERTY_SEARCH_FAIL_NEXT_LB" />
    <RuntimeVariable name="REF_YES_TEL" recipient="no" phonenumber_type="phone">
      <RuntimeVariable name="Number">07444019309</RuntimeVariable>
    </RuntimeVariable>
    <RuntimeVariable name="MOBILE_YN" />
    <RuntimeVariable name="REF_YES_EMAIL_ADDRESS" recipient="no" />
    <RuntimeVariable name="REF_NO_TEL" recipient="no" phonenumber_type="phone">
      <RuntimeVariable name="Number">07444019309</RuntimeVariable>
    </RuntimeVariable>
    <RuntimeVariable name="PR_N_MOBILE_YN" />
    <RuntimeVariable name="REF_NO_EMAIL_ADDRESS" recipient="no" />
    <RuntimeVariable name="CLOSE_2_LB" />
  </RuntimePage>
</RuntimeScript>'))) V(YourXMLColumn);
```